# Finding roots of $\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty n z^n q^{n^2} =0 $ , $z_k=u_k(q)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, roots, theta-functions

[The Jacobi triple product identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product) is:
$$F(z,q)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n})(1+zq^{2n-1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2}  $$ 
where $|q|<1$

All roots of  $F(z,q)=0$ for z can be expressed as:

$$z_k=-q^{2k-1}$$  where $k$ is an integer

I would like to find similar expansion for  $\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty n z^n q^{n^2} $ like The Jacobi triple product identity.

$$Q(z,q)=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty n z^n q^{n^2} $$

where $|q|<1$.

It is obvious that

$z=1$ and $z=-1$
$$Q(1,q)=Q(-1,q)=0$$

$z=1$ and $z=-1$  are trivial roots for $Q(z,q)=0$

Can we express roots ( $z_k=u_k(q)$) as known functions such as Theta functions , etc?

---

I would like to share my attempt to find $z_k=u_k(q)$:
$$Q(z,q)=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty n z^n q^{n^2} $$
$$Q(z,q)=(z-z^{-1})q+2(z^2-z^{-2})q^4+3(z^3-z^{-3})q^9+4(z^4-z^{-4})q^{16}+5(z^5-z^{-5})q^{25}+.......$$

$$Q(z,q)=(z-z^{-1})q+2[(z-z^{-1})(z+z^{-1})]q^4+3[(z-z^{-1})(z^2+1+z^{-2})]q^9+4[(z-z^{-1})(z^3+z+z^{-1}+z^{-3})]q^{16}+5[(z-z^{-1})(z^4+z^2+1+z^{-2}+z^{-4})]q^{25}+.......$$

$$Q(z,q)=(z-z^{-1}) \big[ q+2(z+z^{-1})q^4+3[(z+z^{-1})^2-1)]q^9+4[(z+z^{-1})^3-2(z+z^{-1})]q^{16}+5[(z+z^{-1})^4-3(z+z^{-1})^2+1]q^{25}+.......\big]$$

We can easily see that trivial roots $z=1,-1$ can be gotten from  $z-z^{-1}=0$

Other roots can be gotten from

$$Q(z,q)=(z-z^{-1})\big[(q-3q^9+5q^{25}+....)+(z+z^{-1})(2q^4-8q^{16}+...)+(z+z^{-1})^2(3q^9-15q^{25}+....)+(z+z^{-1})^3(4q^{16}+....)+(z+z^{-1})^4(5q^{25}+....)+...\big]$$

We can write that

$$Q(z,q)=(z-z^{-1})\big(a_0(q)+a_1(q)(z+z^{-1})+a_2(q)(z+z^{-1})^2+a_3(q)(z+z^{-1})^3+a_4(q)(z+z^{-1})^4+.....\big)$$

$$z+z^{-1}=T(q)$$

If $T(q)$ is root of  $a_0(q)+a_1(q)T(q)+a_2(q)T(q)^2+a_3(q)T(q)^3+.....=0$

2 roots have a relationship  :

$u_1=\frac{T(q)+\sqrt{T(q)^2-4}}{2}$;

$u_{-1}=\frac{T(q)-\sqrt{T(q)^2-4}}{2}$

$u_1=\frac{1}{u_{-1}}$

Some relations for $ Q(z,q) $ may also be helpful

$$Q(zq^2,q)=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty n z^n q^{n^2+2n} $$
$$zqQ(zq^2,q)=zq\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty n z^n q^{n^2+2n} $$

$$zqQ(zq^2,q)=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty n z^{n+1} q^{n^2+2n+1} $$

$$zqQ(zq^2,q)=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty (n-1) z^{n} q^{n^2} $$
$$zqQ(zq^2,q)=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty n z^{n} q^{n^2}  -\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^{n} q^{n^2}$$

$$Q(z,q)-zqQ(zq^2,q)= \sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^{n} q^{n^2}$$

$$Q(zq^2,q)-zq^3Q(zq^4,q)= \sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^{n} q^{n^2+2n}$$
$$zqQ(zq^2,q)-z^2q^4Q(zq^4,q)= \sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^{n+1} q^{n^2+2n+1}$$

$$zqQ(zq^2,q)-z^2q^4Q(zq^4,q)=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^{n} q^{n^2}$$

$$Q(z,q)-zqQ(zq^2,q)=zqQ(zq^2,q)-z^2q^4Q(zq^4,q)$$

$$Q(z,q)+z^2q^4Q(zq^4,q)=2zqQ(zq^2,q)   \tag{1}$$

Other relation can be written as:
$$\frac{\partial F(z,q)}{\partial z}=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty n z^{n-1} q^{n^2}$$

$$Q(z,q)=z\frac{\partial F(z,q)}{\partial z}  \tag{2}$$

Thank you for answers and comments

I wish Healthy days for all people in the world.

EDIT:31/03/2020

Because $u_1, u_{-1}$ roots have relation  :

$$u_1=\frac{1}{u_{-1}}$$

and if roots are $u_k(q)$ :  where $k$ positive integer

We can write the expansion of $Q(z,q)$ as:

$$Q(z,q)=A(q) (z-z^{-1})\prod\limits_{k=1}^{ \infty }(1-\frac{z}{u_k(q)})(1-\frac{z^{-1}}{u_k(q)})  \tag{3}$$

The relation (3) satisfies $Q(z^{-1},q)=-Q(z,q)$

$A(q),u_k(q)$ only depend on $q$. I haven't found them yet . I have been looking for methods to find them.

Thanks for any helps to find them.

EDIT:  7th April 2020

I would like to add another relation . That can be helpful to find  $A(q),u_k(q)$

$$F(z,q)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n})(1+zq^{2n-1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1})$$

$$\ln F(z,q)=\ln \prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n})+  \ln \prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty } (1+zq^{2n-1}) + \ln \prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1})$$

$$\ln F(z,q)=\ln \prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n})+   \sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \ln(1+zq^{2n-1}) +  \sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \ln(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1})$$

If we derivate both side for $z$;

$$\cfrac{\frac{\partial F(z,q)}{\partial z} }{F(z,q)}=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{q^{2n-1}}{1+zq^{2n-1}}-\sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{z^{-2}q^{2n-1}}{1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}}$$

$$\cfrac{z\frac{\partial F(z,q)}{\partial z} }{F(z,q)}=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{zq^{2n-1}}{1+zq^{2n-1}}-\sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{z^{-1}q^{2n-1}}{1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}}$$

$$\cfrac{Q(z,q)}{F(z,q)}=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{zq^{2n-1}}{1+zq^{2n-1}}-\sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{z^{-1}q^{2n-1}}{1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}}$$

$$\cfrac{Q(z,q)}{F(z,q)}=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{zq^{2n-1}}{1+zq^{2n-1}}- \frac{z^{-1}q^{2n-1}}{1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}}$$

$$\cfrac{Q(z,q)}{F(z,q)}=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{(z-z^{-1})q^{2n-1}}{1+q^{2(2n-1)}+q^{2n-1}(z+z^{-1})}$$

$$Q(z,q)=(z-z^{-1})F(z,q)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{q^{2n-1}}{1+q^{2(2n-1)}(1+\frac{q^{2n-1}}{1+q^{2(2n-1)}}(z+z^{-1}))}$$

$$Q(z,q)=(z-z^{-1})F(z,q)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{q^{2n-1}}{1+q^{2(2n-1)}}\big(1-\frac{q^{2n-1}}{1+q^{2(2n-1)}}(z+z^{-1})+\frac{q^{2(2n-1)}}{(1+q^{2(2n-1)})^2}(z+z^{-1})^2+.....\big]$$

$$Q(z,q)=(z-z^{-1})F(z,q)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \frac{q^{2n-1}}{1+q^{2(2n-1)}}-\frac{q^{2(2n-1)}}{(1+q^{2(2n-1)})^2}(z+z^{-1})+\frac{q^{3(2n-1)}}{(1+q^{2(2n-1)})^3}(z+z^{-1})^2-.....\big)$$

$$Q(z,q)=(z-z^{-1})F(z,q)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^ \infty \sum\limits_{k = 0}^ \infty (-1)^k\frac{q^{(k+1)(2n-1)}}{(1+q^{2(2n-1)})^{k+1}}(z+z^{-1})^{k}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $\Im(\tau)> 0$ let $P_\tau = \frac{-1-\tau}{2}+(0,1)+(0,\tau)$ be the fundamental parallelogram and (differientating as function of $z$) $$f(z;\tau)=\frac{\theta'(z;q)}{\theta(z;q)},\qquad \theta(z,q)= \sum_n e^{2i\pi nz} e^{i\pi n^2 \tau},\quad f(z+1;\tau)=f(z;\tau)$$ $$ f(z+\tau;\tau)=f(z;\tau)-2i\pi $$

The Jacobi triple product tells the zeros of $\theta(z;q)$ thus the poles of $f(z;\tau)$, it has one pole on $P_\tau$.

To find the number of zeros of $f(z;\tau)$ on $P_\tau$ look at $$\int_{\partial P_\tau} f(z;\tau)dz=2i\pi$$ 
Thus $f(z;\tau)$ has two zeros on $P_\tau$.

$\theta'(z;q)$ has a simple zero at $z=n$ and $z=n+1/2$. On the parallelograms $P_\tau+n+m\tau$ with $m \ne 0$ there are two zeros but their exact location is probably a special function of $\tau,m$, and not an elliptic integral.